# Chaging the background color of an input field with JQuery

Tags: jquery, input, field, background-color

I am trying to change the background colour of one input field on a form based on the value of another input field. While the following code works correctly for changing the readonly property of the field, none of the following 3 lines of code, as well as many others I have tried, seem to work for changing the background colour.

```
               if(names[6] == "Yes") {

                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').val(names[3]);

                    $('add_at_inv2_client').prop('background-color','#fefefe');
                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('object.style.backgroundColor="#fefefe"');
                    $('add_at_inv2_client').css('background', '#fefefe');

                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',false);

                } else {

                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').val(names[3]);

                    $('add_at_inv2_client').prop('background-color','#cccccc');
                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('object.style.backgroundColor="#cccccc"');
                    $('add_at_inv2_client').css('background', '#cccccc');

                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',true);

                }
```

Can someone please help me achieve this?

Thanks,
Adri

Comment: you need the # in your tag id for the .css and the .prop for the backkground colors.

Comment: Better share the html as well so others can know whats the element you are trying change colors

Answer (score 1):

You have missing `#` in your select code,
so change
`$('add_at_inv2_client').css('background', '#fefefe');`
 to
`$('#add_at_inv2_client').css('background', '#fefefe');`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ID property

```
$('#add_at_inv2_client').css('background', '#cccccc'); // # missing from start
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method for `background-color` property. And use . for class and # for id before selector.

```
$('#selector').css({"background-color":"#fefefe"});
```

Comment: I am wondering why your reputation drop so much in the past?We need to avoid it

Comment: @lucumt you misspelled my name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I have been copying and pasting all those trials without the #

I have now settled for this and it seems to be working fine!

```
$('#add_at_inv2_client').attr('style','background-color:#fefefe;');
```

Thank you all,
Adri